existence of global solution to ODE
I'm trying to show that the IVP
$$
\dot{x}(t) = \frac{t^3 x(t)^3}{1 + x(t)^2} + \exp(t) \cos(t), \quad x(t_0) = x_0
$$
has a unique solution on $\mathbb{R}$ for any $(t_0,x_0) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.
I have already shown the existence of a maximal solution using the fact that the right-hand side of the equation is $ C^{0,1^-}(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}) $, meaning it is continuous and locally lipschitz w.r.t $x$. So we have a unique maximal solution $y$ on an interval $J=(t_-,t_+)$.
I am having difficulties showing that $|y|$ doesn't blow up as $t$ approaches $t_-$ or $t_+$. Can someone help me with that?

If $I$ is a bounded interval the right hand side is Lipschitz in $x$ on $I \times \mathbb{R}$. By Picard Lindelöf all solutions exist on $I$. Since $I$ was arbitrary all solutions exist on $\mathbb{R}$.

@Gerd Wouldn't your argument imply that $y'(t)=y(t)^2$ would not have a blow-up in finite time?

Have you tried to use Gronwall? You have $$\vert x'(t)\vert \leq \vert x(t)\vert \cdot \vert t\vert^3+e^t.$$

@Schraven No. Here the right hand side is not Lipschitz in $y$ on $I\times\mathbb{R}$. If $f\in C(\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ is such that for each bounded Interval $I$ there is a constant $L_I$ with $|f(t,x)-f(t,y)| \le L_I|x-y|$ on $I  \times \mathbb{R}$ then all solutions of $x'=f(t,x)$ exist on $\mathbb{R}$.

@Gerd Sorry, I thought the first variable was $x$.

@SeverinSchraven How do you get $ \vert x'(t)\vert \leq \vert x(t)\vert \cdot \vert t\vert^3+e^t?$ isn't it $\vert x'(t)\vert \leq \vert x(t)\vert^3 \cdot \vert t\vert^3+e^t$?

@Mathbds If you drop the $1$ your fraction gets bigger and you can cancel the $x^2$.

Or if you want to keep the expressions far from being singular, use $|x^3|\le|x|(1+x^2)$. The next step of course is the same.

Let $x(t)$ be the unique solution in the maximal interval $(t_-,t_+)$. If $t_+=\infty$, it is done. Otherwise
$$ \lim_{t\to t_+^+}|x(t)|=\infty. \tag1$$
From the equation, one has
$$ |x'|\le t^3|x|+e^t$$
and hence, for $t_0<t<t_+$,
$$ |x(t)|=\bigg|\int_{t_0}^tx'(s)ds+x_0\bigg|\le\int_{t_0}^t|x'(s)|ds+|x_0|\le\int_{t_0}^ts^3|x(s)|ds+e^t-e^{t_0}+|x_0|.$$
By Gronwall's inequality, one has
$$ |x(t)|\le\bigg[e^t-e^{t_0}+|x_0|\bigg]\exp(\frac14(t^4-t_0^4)). \tag2$$
Letting $t\to t_+^+$ in (2) will give the result contradictory to (1).

I hope this time it will be ok. Thanks @LutzLehmann

Yes, that is now correct.
